# Is it possible to retrieve Inactive Process builder versions?

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, metadata-api

We use process builder heavily and sometimes I need to go and see what is there in the Inactive ones. I prefer downloading all flows(including Inactive) and searching in vs code.

I tried the below two commands and both are retrieving only the active version.

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve --metadatatype=Flow

sfdx force:source:retrieve --metadatatype=FlowDefinition
```

How do I download the active and inactive versions?

Comment: From what I've seen, post-43 MDAPI does not retrieve the active version: it gets the *latest* version, active or not. This means, quite horrifyingly, that if there is an inactive version newer than the active one, you cannot see the metadata of the active version at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The versioned [`FlowDefinition`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flowdefinition.htm) object is no longer recommended as of API 44.0, in favor of the unversioned [`Flow`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm#md_flow_upgrade), which is the point at which behavior around Flow versions changed in the Metadata API.

Using API version 43.0 or prior to retrieve `FlowDefinition` should return the original versioned files.

Comment: But with the big caveat: Any features that are post-43 in your Flows or PBs will be retrieved unreliably.